# Dynamic Android Button Styling

Tags: java, android-view, android-button

I want to style a button in java. Need to place a background Image and Apearance Changes.

But its not picking up the style:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dynamicpan);
Button btn = new Button(this,null,R.style.productButton); 
btn.setText(arrProducts[i].toString());
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_style);
linearLayout.addView(btn); 


 <style name="productButton">
   <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
</style>
```

Can anyone please help me out to fix this issue?